# Shell scripting test command

Tags: shell, design-patterns, testing, scripting

I write the following shell script.

```
#! /bin/sh

foo=asdfqwer/asdfxv

if [ $foo = */* ]
then
    echo bad
else
    echo good
fi
```

in test command, we could compare string and pattern like this,

```
[ string = pattern ]

[ string == pattern ]
```

however, the above script always print "good" in the terminal and also has error as below:

```
[ : asdfqwer/asdfxv : unexpected operator
```

Can someone tells me why and how to compare a stirng and a pattern in shell scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` command (or `[` command), does not do globbed comparison. Instead, the shell is expanding the `*/*` to match files in your directory, and substituting them in to that command. Presumably, one of the filenames gets parsed as an operator to the `[` command, and is invalid.

The best way to compare against globs is `case`:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=asdfqwer/asdfxv

case "$foo" in
   */*) echo bad ;;
   *) echo good ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$foo" == "*/*" ]
then
    echo bad
else
    echo good
```

You need double equals for comparison and looks like string comparisons require double quotes.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/209/bournebash-shell-scripts-string-comparison/

Comment: I think it will not work since only foo=/ the result is bad. Otherwise, the result is good all the time

Comment: `==` is not POSIX compliant.